# Changing Slots on Qt Menu Bar (with image)

Tags: c++, qt

this is more of a functionality question than programming question but I can't find any other idiot operators like me out there that are having the same problem as me, or haven't figured it out themselves.

I've got a good basic understanding of CLI C++ so I want to get into the Qt Framework. I'm using their tutorials to get started...
http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtdoc/gettingstartedqt.html#adding-menu-items

The tutorial says that all I need is to "right-click an action and select Go to slot > triggered()."

The image below shows in red circles two of the primary places I've tried right clicking. I've also tried going through the menu and looking for things but to no avail. (Question continued below picture.)

[image: https://i1148.photobucket.com/albums/o572/slassen/StackOverflow/54cc9f53-57a1-4bba-b3a2-38ced2f72ee8.jpg]

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong here or am I reading this wrong? Thanks in advance.
FYI the open button and save button under central widget is for the Open and Save buttons I added, NOT for the menu toolbar open and save functions.

Comment: Not an answer, just a few words of encouragement: the QWidget Designer can be unintuitive, it's not you being an an idiot. Also, it may be easier to use if you first learn to write the GUI by hand (it's easy With Qt layouts, and many prefer it over the Designer).

Comment: Thanks hyde, it's appreciated. I assumed that it would be easier learning backward from Qt Creator since I could just look at their libraries and classes and how they made it work based on the design I wanted. Maybe I was wrong! Haha... Well **cheers**. Here's looking for an answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Near the bottom of Qt Creator find the tabs "Action Editor" and "Signals & Slots Editor".  Click the "Action Editor" tab to show a list of all the actions in your UI.  You should be able to right-click these items and select "Go to slot...".

Comment: Very simple. I did mess with that section but somehow I didn't do it right. Thanks!